# How to index the output of read.table from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what I did:

```
data = pd.read_table("data.txt")
print(data)
```

And here is what the result of the data frame looks like:

```
    Day1  Day2  Day3  Day4  Day5  Day6  Day7
0  95.01 76.21 61.54 40.57  5.79 20.28  1.53
1  23.11 45.65 79.19 93.55 35.29 19.87 74.68
2  60.68  1.85 92.18 91.69 81.32 60.38 44.51
3  48.60 82.14 73.82 41.03  0.99 27.22 93.18
4  89.13 44.47 17.63 89.36 13.89 19.88 46.60
```

The problem is, python does not realize that the 'days' can be indexed as columns as I did in this:

```
print(data.loc[:,"Day3"])
```

But it resulted this error:

> axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
>
> KeyError: 'the label [Day3] is not in the [columns]'

I want to index the columns of Day3 and Day5 for example. How can I do it?
Also, can I use read_csv ?

Comment: Your desired output is just those two columns?

Comment: `df[['Day3', 'Day5']]` should give you what you want

Comment: @chrisz This is just an example, but I can select many. So I don't want to set the attribute `names` in the `read_csv` and name it the columns I want. Is there something easier?

Comment: You're going to have to post a dataframe showing your desired outcome, I'm unsure of what you mean.

Comment: @sacul It gives: `Index(['Day1  Day2  Day3  Day4  Day5  Day6  Day7'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @chrisz This `df[['Day3', 'Day5']]` gives me this error `KeyError: "['Day2' 'Day3'] not in index"`

Comment: @chrisz My desired output for now is the two columns Day3 and Day5

Comment: @sacul I just imported it with `pandas.read_table`. What do you think I should do with my text file? knowing that its format is like the one posted in the question.

Comment: If your `txt` is *exactly* as your df in the question (with the same spacing arrangment and everything), you can try: `data = pd.read_table("data.txt", sep=r'\s+')`

Comment: @sacul It's done. Thanks a lot :) I googled `sep=r'\s+'` and found that it is used when there a tab of more than one character. How did that solve the problem and the separation was just one space between each element? I also didn't understand the `s+` part

Comment: @EzzEddinAbdullah, glad it helped! If you look at your text file, you'll see that it's not actually always just one space separating the values: for instance, look between the index column and the first column...

Comment: I think you might have whitespace in your column headers.  if you data.head().to_dict() you might see spaces trailing Day3 like 'Day3 '. If this is the problem, you can correct using `data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: @sacul Yes, it actually has some longer spaces I didn't see

Comment: @ScottBoston `data.head().to_dict()` helped me visualize the entries in just one line but `str.strip()` didn't strip the spaces